# Auto calculate textboxes value in edittemplate of gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

1. The content page has two Grid-views, ‘gv_Purchase’ and ‘gv_PurchaseDetails’
2. On Page_Load , ‘gv_Purchase’ is displaying data from ‘tbl_Purchase’ table of SQL.
3. To get information in detail users have to select any particular row by clicking on corresponding link button (‘Select’).
4. ‘gv_PurchaseDetails’ will be visible and will display the related data regarding selected row of previous Grid-view (‘gv_Purchase’) from ‘tbl_PurchaseDetails’ table of SQL.
5. ‘gv_PurchaseDetails’ has two template fields, ‘Rate’ and ‘Quantity’.  Users can change value from Edit-template mode by clicking on link button (‘Edit’).
6. When users enter value in ‘text_Rate’ and ’ text_Quantity’, on key-up event calls a function to display value(‘text_Rate’  * ’ text_Quantity’) in ‘label_Amount’ of the row. After that users will/have to store data by clicking on link button(‘Update’).

I am unable to execute point no.6. Please let me know how should I send value of text boxes in JavaScript function.

Comment: In which language you're trying to do these things?

Comment: can you edit your code into the post?

Comment: @ Hisham Bawa, I am very new in .Net rather 1st time i am here.so can't understand what u asking